# Cannot create new bot on Xcode Server

Tags: xcode, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I can view the existing bots within Xcode, and I can edit them, but clicking "Create Bot..." does not give me the popup where I edit the new bot. I've tried this both in a local machine and within Xcode on the server machine, with the same results. I could not find any documentation of this error online, but I was wondering if anyone else has experienced it.

If it's related, I recently had to reset the Xcode server with `xcrun xcscontrol --reset`

For reference, I'm running Xcode Server 5.1, with Xcode 7.3 (7D175)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes when that happens I remove the server from my list of servers in my Xcode and re-add it

Comment: I actually did that, but unfortunately it didn't help. Curiously, I'm now able to click on the gear button and select "Create Bot..." that way, but right clicking on an existing bot and selecting "Create Bot..." still does nothing.